# Spinner is being displayed properly but not removed on being called again

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, slds

I have the following component code

```
<div style="text-align:center">
       <lightning:spinner aura:id="mySpinner" class="slds-hide"/>
</div>
```

and the following js helper code

```
getAccountRequestListHelper : function(component,event,helper){

        var spinner = component.find("mySpinner");
        $A.util.toggleClass(spinner, "slds-show");

        console.log('inside get account list helper'+component.get("v.ucn"));

        var action = component.get("c.searchAccounts");
        console.log('Here 1');

        var input = component.find("assignedToInput");
        var assignedToId = input ? input.get('v.value') : null;
        console.log('Here 2'+assignedToId);
        console.log('assignedToInput'+assignedToId);
        action.setParams({
            ucn : component.get("v.ucn"),
            requestSource : component.get("v.requestSource"),
            status : component.get("v.status"),
            assignedto : assignedToId,
            fromdate : component.get("v.requestDateFrom")
            //requestDateTo : component.get("v.requestDateTo")
        });

        action.setCallback(this, function(response){

            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                $A.util.toggleClass(spinner, "slds-hide");
                console.log('inside success'+response.getReturnValue().length);
                if(response.getReturnValue().length > 0){
                    component.set("v.wrapAccountList", response.getReturnValue());
                    $A.util.toggleClass(spinner, "slds-hide");
                    console.log('Has it entered here');
                    console.log(component.get("v.wrapAccountList"));
                }
               else{

                }
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);   
    },
```

Here the toggle spinner is initially hidden. When I click on a button it calls the method. The spinner is then displayed. However, later after the success, it is not being removed. Am I doing something wrong here

Comment: I am using var spinner = component.find("mySpinner"); to fetch

Comment: You need to remove the show css and add the hide. I see all you are doing to adding the hid but leaving the show

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this, we can simply take help of a **Boolean** type **attribute** like this:

```
<aura:component ...>
  <aura:attribute name="isProcessing" type="Boolean" default="false" />

  <!-- more attributes/handler/events -->


  <!-- more html -->

  <div style="text-align:center">
    <lightning:spinner class="{!((v.isProcessing)? '': 'slds-hide')}"/>
  </div>

  <!-- more html -->
</aura:component>
```

And in your **helper** use this.

```
({
  getAccountRequestListHelper: function (component, event, helper) {

    helper.startProcessing(component);

    console.log('inside get account list helper' + component.get("v.ucn"));

    var action = component.get("c.searchAccounts");
    console.log('Here 1');

    var input = component.find("assignedToInput");
    var assignedToId = input ? input.get('v.value') : null;
    console.log('Here 2' + assignedToId);
    console.log('assignedToInput' + assignedToId);
    action.setParams({
      ucn: component.get("v.ucn"),
      requestSource: component.get("v.requestSource"),
      status: component.get("v.status"),
      assignedto: assignedToId,
      fromdate: component.get("v.requestDateFrom")
      //requestDateTo : component.get("v.requestDateTo")
    });

    action.setCallback(this, function (response) {

      var state = response.getState();
      if (state === "SUCCESS") {
        $A.util.toggleClass(spinner, "slds-hide");
        console.log('inside success' + response.getReturnValue().length);
        if (response.getReturnValue().length > 0) {
          component.set("v.wrapAccountList", response.getReturnValue());
          $A.util.toggleClass(spinner, "slds-hide");
          console.log('Has it entered here');
          console.log(component.get("v.wrapAccountList"));
        }
        else {

        }
      }
      helper.stopProcessing(component);
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
  },
  startProcessing: function (c) {
    /* this will show the <lightning:spinner /> */
    c.set('v.isProcessing', true);
  },
  stopProcessing: function (c) {
    /* this will hide the <lightning:spinner /> */
    c.set('v.isProcessing', false);
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks @itzmukeshy7 it works. What I would like to understand is that. Can't it be achieved with the way I had done? Hide and Show slds?

Comment: That is also possible but in that way, you have to add/remove classes `slds-hide/slds-show` as you have added slds-hide so just adding `slds-show` won't show the element you have to remove the `slds-hide` as well to show the element;

Answer (score 1):

Don't add show class , just toggle the Hide Class..

I think the problem is you are adding the "slds-show" class to the spinner. Don't add the show class, just remove the "slds-hide" from the element and then add it back.
Toggle - add the class if it's not there and removes it if it's there. You added the "show" class but didn't remove it.

It tried this, You can also try and see the css class in the element. you can use any Apex controller for testing.

```
  aura:component description="SpinnerTest" controller="AccountsControllerList">
        <lightning:button variant="brand" label="Toggle" onclick="{!c.callFunction}"/>
        <aura:attribute name="accounts" type="List" />
        <aura:attribute name = "gotIt" type= "string"/>
        {!v.gotIt}
        <div id = "spinnerDiv">
            <lightning:spinner variant="brand" size = "large" aura:id = "sps" class="slds-hide"/>
        </div>
</aura:component>
```

Client Controller

```
({
    callFunction: function(component,event,helper){
        var spin = component.find('sps');
        $A.util.toggleClass(spin,'slds-hide'); // removing hide class to show the spinner.
        var action = component.get('c.getAccounts');
        action.setCallback(this,function(response){
           component.set("v.gotIt", 'Response Recieved');
           $A.util.toggleClass(spin,'slds-hide'); // adding the hide class
           console.log('response', response);
           component.set('v.accounts',response.getReturnValue());
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

Comment: This works. Thanks a ton.But,  I had to mark the previous answer as correct as it came it first.